# MS Excel - SumProduct formula with Loop

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, sumifs

I have 4 arrays of data where I need a some product but with few conditions.

I'm unable to solve that and I'm not good at creating VBA functions as well.

Can anyone please help?

Apologies for the lack of clarity.

I'll try to give more details here. Please refer the below workbook.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XVEe4Sjw6ZeAh-7jyeLDs7Tp5RRQD20i/view?usp=sharing

Investment value is `Row 2 * Row 3`.
This value is carried across all the months after amortization given in row 4. 5th row is converting the yearly value into monthly value (1/12).

So, in the first month 50 is invested and the value at the beginning of the month after amort of 100%, So 50 is available for month 1. This is further converted into monthly values with the help of row 5. So, the result for month 1 will be `100 * 50% * 100% * 8.33%` = `4.1667` [Cell I9]

For the month 2, the value available is,

Value carried from month 1 after amort `(100 * 50% * 99%)` +
New amount in month 2 `(102 * 50% * 100%)`

The above value is converted into the monthly value again with the help of row 5.

Result for month 2 => Cell I10 = `(100 * 50% * 99% * 8.33%) + (102 * 50% * 100% * 8.33%)` = `8.375`

Similarly, for month 3 the value will be,

Month 1's investment `(100*50%*98%*8.33%)` +
Month 2's investment `(102*50%*99%*8.33%)` +
Month 3's investment `(104*50%*100%*8.33%)`

I need the above calculation to happen in single cell for all the months. I tried sumproduct with offset. But I couldn't.

Comment: What you are trying to do? Show only one sample and desired output.

Comment: Hi, I have saved a sample excel file in the below link. Total column is the result I'm trying to achieve. I hope this will give more clarity.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1837yV60jkHkaCFsIiNXtxa7WA4fUoc70/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For month2 in this formula `=B2*B3*C4*C5` you have used month1 data? What is logic?

Comment: Its like calculating the value of month 1 deposit after amortisation (using array 3 - C4) and identifying the value for one month (1/12 - approx - array 4 - C5)

Comment: I don't know what your end goal is. To have the totals without the helpers? Paste this formula in `J9` and copy down: `="="&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("+",1,IFERROR(FORMULATEXT(B9),""),IFERROR(FORMULATEXT(C9),""),IFERROR(FORMULATEXT(D9),"")),"=","")` then copy them and paste as value and confirm the formulas with enter and you'll have the desired outcome in one formula without needing the helpers anymore. Is that what's requested?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've edited my question to provide more details. Please have a look.

Comment: Is "% used for investment" & "Year to month conversion" always be a constant?

Comment: No. They're all dynamic. Just for example I've kept same.

Comment: Alright, now I can 'sorted' (I hope! :) i.e. my proposal below derives a version that caters for @Anitha comment; "[parameters]... they're all dynamic", AND I've given an analytical soln. which should satisfy requirements originally posted (i.e. based upon what I understood to be 'static/specific parameters provided within the sample data/screenshot by O.P...!  phew! off to other Qs - about time already! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***REVISED*** *(based upon comment 'all values are dynamic)*...

Plug this into cell b6 per screenshot, drag to right:

```
=SUM($B2:B2*$B3:B3*$B4:B4*$B5:B5)
```

This will evaluate the sums you have indicated below the 24 month table [at top your linked spreadsheet] i.e. which correspond to respective months 1,2,... etc.

[image: Application of 'single-cell' function that caters for 'fully dynamic parameters' within the table.]

### PREVIOUS SOLN:

**HIGH LEVEL**

Let cell A1 contain the month (=,   ℕ).  Plug this into excel to get the sum of the  terms for k = 1,...,:

```
=A1*(98-A1+(3/2)*(1+A1)+(1/50)*((1+A1)*((2*A1+1)/6-A1/2-1/2)+A1))/24
```

**DERIVATION**

Your sequence has  terms; let () be the th such term:

```
() = (100+2(−1))(1−(−)/100)/24
```

where `1 < 2 < ,..., ≤  ≤ ,.., . Let () be the sum over  = 1, ... ,` . It immediately follows that:

```
()= (1/24) ∑(100+2(−1))(1−(−)/100);   ℕ;  = 1,2,..,
```

Elementary simplification yields the following:

```
() = (1/24)  { 98 -  + 1.5 (1 + ) + 0.02 {(1+)((2+1)/6 - /2 - 1/2) +r } }
```

( ☻)

**CHECKS**

| (A1) | Result | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4.17 | √ |
| 2 | 8.38 | √ |
| 3 | 12.62 | √ |
| 4 | 16.91 | √ |
| 5 | 21.24 | √ |
| .. | .. | n/a |
| 24 | 109.81 | √ |

Comment: Kindly accept if this resolves, per guidelines, for other users.

Comment: (thumbs up if it works for you would be great too btw! :)

Comment: Genius you're. Thanks a lot for your effort and simple formula.
I made 2 changes to made it work perfectly as I wanted (I might not be clear in my question)

Reversing the "% after amortisation" and relative reference of "Year to Month Conversion".

B6=SUM($B2:B2*($B3:B3)* INDEX($B4:B4,N(IF({1},MAX(COLUMN($B4:B4))-COLUMN($B4:B4)+1)))*B5:B5)

Comment: Glad it worked out in the end post changes - best thanks I can receive is an upvote - but happy with accepted resolve as most important thing! :)  (PS- best bet re: any revisions to request would be to update to Q, screenshot and / or uploaded examples well in advance.  I 'turn-off' all other things re prob. / Q at hand! :)

Comment: Haha, thanks Anitha. Best of luck re your future ventures/wishes and, of course, Excel projects! :) J

Comment: May I know.. (as a n00b seeing a `SUM()` used with range multiplication for the 1st time ) will dropping the bracket at `($B3:B3)` make any difference on the calculation?

Comment: (sometimes it does/can make a difference.  but I don't think this is one of those cases so you should be fine- give it a go and let me know if something breaks. Could make for an interesting / insightful stackoverflow Q :)

Comment: @p._phidot_ I know you asked this Q ages ago (06/21) - but btw. it makes no difference in this case (i.e. "dropping the bracket at ($B3:b3)")...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, really appreciate it. ( :

Comment: No problem @p._phidot_  ☺